# Mongoose Pre Save Method not triggering

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a new document within my DB and before saving that I want to perform another action. but the `pre save` method does not execute.

**My Code to Create New Document:**

```
let create = (req, res) => {


   let newProposal = Proposal();

   newProposal.sector = req.body.sector;
   newProposal.client = req.body.client;
   newProposal.owner = req.body.owner;
   newProposal.proposalTitle = req.body.proposalTitle;
   newProposal.proposalRegion = req.body.proposalRegion;
   newProposal.clientContact = req.body.clientContact;


  newProposal.save()
    .then((savedProposal) => {return _updateUser(req.decoded._id, savedProposal)})
    .then(() => {return _checkClientExists(req.body.client)})
    .then((client) => {return _updateClientList(client, req.body)})
    .then(() => {res.json(newProposal)})
    .catch(err => {sendJsonResponse(res, 500, err)})
};
```

**My Pre Save Code:**

```
proposalSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
   console.log("Does not work");
});
```

I have also tried using `pre validate`.

**What am I doing wrong? I've been stuck for hours.**

**Update: Proposal Schema Code:**

```
const proposalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

proposalNo: Number,
proposalUrls: {type: String, default: 'none'},
proposalStatus: {type: String, default: 'live' ,set: toLower},
sector: {type: String, set: toLower},
client: {type: String, set: toLower},
owner: {type: String, set: toLower},
proposalTitle: {type: String, set: toLower},
proposalRegion: String,
clientContact: {type: String, set: toLower},


dateCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},

});

function toLower(data) {
   return data.toLowerCase();
}

proposalSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
   console.log("Does not work");
});

mongoose.model('Proposals', proposalSchema);
```

**Update 2:**

```
const Counter = require('../models/counter');

proposalSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    let doc = this;

    Counter.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: 'entityId'},{$inc: { seq: 1}},{"upsert": true,"new": true  }, function(error, counter)   {
        if(error) {
            return next(error);
        }

        doc.proposalNo = counter.seq;
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post more of the `Proposal` model declaration?

Comment: @TsvetanGanev please see updated questions for code.

Comment: How do you export the model? I don't see any assignment of the result from 
 `mongoose.model()`.

Answer (score 0):

You must instantiate your model with the `new` keyword. Citing the Mongoose documentation:

> Models are fancy constructors compiled from our Schema definitions.

```
let newProposal = new Proposal();
```

Comment: I've just tried this and thew error still remains. Its been driving me crazy.

Comment: Wait, what is the error thrown? You didn't say your current code threw errors, you said that only the `pre-save` function didn't run.

Comment: Its throws an `internal server error 500` and nothing else. If I remove the my `pre save` code everything works fine.

Comment: You must call `next()` inside of your `pre-save` function, otherwise Mongoose will handle this as an error.

Comment: ah okay. The above solved my issue. But I have another issue. Instead of console logging my code now I am trying to `increment` a variable within my `pre save`. It console logs but won't increment. Any chance you can help? I've added the new code in my question.

Comment: The first parameter of Counter.findByIdAndUpdate has to be id and not object. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: If you have issues which are unrelated to the original question you asked, please post them in a separate question, since people won't be able to find an answer to the question specified in the title.